# oh-my-zsh agnoster RPROMPT

Tags: vim, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to show vim status using RPROMPT in agnoster.  Does anyone know how to add this functionality?  I've been able to modify the agnoster.zsh-theme to add a newline to my long prompt, but adding an RPROMPT after PROMPT in that file doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I've switched from agnoster to avit.  I think I like avit better.  It's more lite-weight, and it shows vim status with an RPROMPT.  In agnoster, I added a function and an RPROMPT entry right after PROMPT in the agnoster.zsh-theme file.  It didn't work.  I'm still not thrilled with avit.  It shows three left arrows when in insert mode, but it doesn't say insert.  I think it should.

Comment: What's particularly odd is that I have the vi-mode plugin in which MODE_INDICATOR is set to "%{$fg_bold[red]%}<%{$fg[red]%}<<%{$reset_color%}"  I changed it to "%{$fg_bold[red]%}<%{$fg[red]%}<<NORMAL%{$reset_color%}"  Nothing changed, however, because MODE_INDICATOR is also set in avit.zsh-theme.  There I've set it to "%{$fg_bold[yellow]%}<%{$fg[red]%}<<NORMAL%{$reset_color%}"  I would like to add an if then statement to have MODE_INDICATOR swiched to "%{$fg_bold[red]%}<%{$fg[red]%}<<INSERT%{$reset_color%}" but I don't know what variable to test.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also ^K no longer deletes the line.

Comment: zsh with oh-my-zsh is so interesting.  There are multiple files for everything.  That is to say, one can edit files that are sourced or edit the .zshrc file.  I was having problems with history search.  The solution was to add the history search plugin.  This seemed very strange to me.  I removed all the keybinding statements from .zshrc as they seem redundant.  I'm learning that reading the Oh-my-zsh documentation is absolutely necessary -- even for a veteran shell-scripter.